# jQuery how to use extra select criteria on a parent node?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to apply a select criteria to a node I have fetched using a jQuery:

```
    let objDIV = $("#selindividual").parent();
```

Now that I have the DIV I want to apply the following to it:

```
    button:contains(\"Submit\")
```

If I was writing this in a node that contains buttons the query might look like this:

```
    $("#idofnode button:contains(\"Submit\")")
```

So the question is how do I do the above when I have the node already?

Comment: can you show your html for better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find()`:

```
let $objDIV = $("#selindividual").parent();
var $button = $objDIV.find('button:contains("Submit")');
```

`children()` would also work, it would just depend what relation the button is to the selected element and how far you want to traverse down the DOM to find it.

Comment: Thank you, I was just looking at filter, would that also work?

Comment: Glad to help. `filter()` wouldn't work in this case as it is for reducing a set of already selected elements.